# delete lines between two matches according third inner pattern using sed

Tags: regex, xml, text, replace, sed

Given:

```
<tagA/>
<tagB>...</tagB>
<setOfFoo>
  <foo>...</foo>
  <foo>
    ...some special content...
  </foo>
  <foo>...</foo>
  <foo>...</foo>
</setOfFoo>
<tagN/>
```

I want to remove the entire node of foo only if has some specific content, I was trying something like:

```
sed '/<foo>/,/special content/d;/special content/,/<\/foo>/d'
# or
sed '/<foo>/,/<\/foo>/{1,/special content/d;/special content/,$d}'
# or
sed '/<foo>/,/<\/foo>/{:a;N;ba;/special content/d}'
```

But none of these worked, any idea?

Remember: other `foo` tags should not be deleted.

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Answer (score 0):

While I was trying a bit more I found the solution:

```
sed '/<foo>/,/special content/N;/special content/,/<\/foo>/d'
```

I still posted the question to help the community.